# Fluent NHibernate - How to use an enumerator to identify subclass?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, join, enums, subclass

Im trying to map the following classes:

```
public abstract class ScheduleType
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeDiscriminatorEnum Discriminator { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedScheduleType : ScehduleType
{
    public virtual bool MyProperty { get; set; }
}



public class ScheduleTypeMap : ClassMap<ScheduleType>
{
    public ScheduleTypeMap()
    {
        Id(p => p.Id);
        Map(p => p.Discriminator).CustomType<TypeDiscriminatorEnum>().Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class DerivedScheduleTypeMap : SubclassMap<DerivedScheduleType>
{
    public DerivedScheduleTypeMap()
    {
        //DiscriminatorValue(TypeDiscriminatorEnum.DerivedSchedule);
        Map(p => p.MyProperty);
    }
}
```

The problem is that queries on ScheduleType joins with all derived tables to find the right one.

I need something that says to NHibernate to join only with the table that represents the right subclass.

Any sugestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which inheritance strategy are you using (https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/inheritance.html)? Can you include a simple example query that exhibits the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<TypeDiscriminatorEnum>("discriminator")` instead of `Map(p => p.Discriminator)`.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve though, because you're talking about joining other tables; discriminators aren't used with table-per-subclass, only in table-per-class-hierarchy.